# laravel passport authorization code grant PKCE requires scope

Tags: php, laravel, security, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I am trying to implement authorization code grant with Laravel Passport and my SPA app. I stumbled upon following issue:

To my knowledge scopes in OAuth are optional, I don't have to request one while asking for code. Even [HERE](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/server-side-apps/authorization-code/) it says that the scope is optional.

So this is what happens:

- I'm going from my SPA to this URL below

```
/oauth/authorize?client_id=5&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth&response_type=code&scope=''&state=hdeqcsaeol7z8569pyl2gmrvl8bdaun4gjxhs78u&code_challenge=LuiQWey7K8Uu1w5Xj0vqOinf0YpXEaYK374PLnelh80=&code_challenge_method=S256
```

- if `scope` is an empty string I get

```
/auth?error=invalid_scope&error_description=The%20requested%20scope%20is%20invalid,%20unknown,%20or%20malformed&hint=Check%20the%20%60%26%23039%3B%26%23039%3B%60%20scope&message=The%20requested%20scope%20is%20invalid,%20unknown,%20or%20malformed
```

- if `scope` is missing altogether, I get

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.","hint":"Code challenge must follow the specifications of RFC-7636.","message":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."}
```

So the problem is that I don't want to use scopes, I don't need them I just want to either get some one default scope or none.

I guess I can define one but this doesn't seem right to me. It was supposed to be optional.

This is how I create all the codes for that flow:

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Regards,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your URL there is `scope=''&` instead of `scope=&`.

Try building the query parameters using `http_build_query()` as [per docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#code-grant-pkce-redirecting-for-authorization).

```php
$query = http_build_query([
    'client_id' => 'client-id',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://third-party-app.com/callback',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope' => '',
    'state' => $state,
    'code_challenge' => $codeChallenge,
    'code_challenge_method' => 'S256',
]);
```

Secondly, your `code_challenge` ends with a `=`.

So you probably should:

- remove the `=` sign at the end of `this.challenge`
- replace `+` with `-` of `this.challenge`
- replace `/` with `_` of `this.challenge`

PHP example

```php
$encoded = base64_encode(hash('sha256', $code_verifier, true));

$codeChallenge = strtr(rtrim($encoded, '='), '+/', '-_');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did try using `scope=&` and it resulted in the second error(the same one as if it was missing). My URL is put together manually in the NuxtJS App so I can't use that function. Do you think it would make a difference in URL?

Comment: I just tried PHP online tool to generate the URL and the result is still the same.

Comment: I've just updated the original question with a screenshot of how I exactly do it. What do you think?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that you mentioned the forbidden character @_@, let time try fixing that.

Comment: It was the damn forbidden characters in the challenge. Thanks Ron, appreciate taking the time!

Answer (score -1):

from what i remember, you can just hardcode scopes to '*' and that should work, i did the same.